# Skype sound volume

Tags: skype

I have Android 2.1update1 and I installed Skype from the Android Market.

In many times when I use it to talk to other people using Skype the talking volume is too loud!

How can I turn it down a little bit?

I just didn't find any volume settings regarding Skype.

Answer (score 1):

Use regular volume button on phone that you use for phone calls or music

Comment: you mean the two volume adjusting buttons on my phones left side, that sets the "ringer volume"? - no, it has no effect. :(

Comment: What mobile phone you have? (I'm just wondering why you still on 2.1)

Comment: LG GT540 & Samsung GT i5800

Comment: You have to adjust it during the call, not in the menus.

Answer (score 1):

When i adjust volume in Skype, it tells me i'm adjusting the `In-call volume`, which is (believe it or not) the same volume setting used when you're in a regular phone call. If you can't adjust this through the settings, i'd try making a normal phone call, turning the volume down, then trying a call in Skype and seeing if the call sounds have changed.

Answer (score 0):

New version of Skype uses system volume for calls. So change there in system preferences and volume in Skype will be changed too.

Comment: I tried all sound adjusting settings in the menu, but with no luck. it's always the same sound volume (in a Skype Test Call). Where exactly is this "System Volume" in Android? please tell :) ty!

Comment: It depends on your Android version. Usually it is somewhere in `Settings->Sound->Volume` menu.

Comment: "Android 2.1update1" - I tried all the "*volume*" adjustments in settings. i think this is a bug. :)

Comment: Try another firmware. Also if you use unofficial ROM, please clear everything you can during update.

Comment: I use the offical firmware. I don't want to use un-offical, trojaned firmware. :P